# Is SP 2019 is section 508 compliant?

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, accessibility

I see [information from MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/accessibility-guidelines) for SP 2016 regarding section 508 complaint. But in this article it was mentioned only for 2016 may be because this is belongs to only SP 2016 version.

[image]

But i don't find any information from Microsoft regarding SharePoint 2019 compatibility with Accessibility guidelines. Does anyone know this information?

Answer (score 0):

I have posted similar question in [tech community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SP-2019-is-section-508-compliant/m-p/739396#M31850) and got the answer. I am answering here for future reference for anyone. Thanks to [Chris](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/169605)

It is here

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/industry-blog/government/2018/09/11/accessibility-conformance-repor...

Search by Product, Add SharePoint and find SharePoint 2019, Section 508 here

[image]